Let $\varphi_a(x)$ denote the solution of the initial-value problem: $\begin{cases} \dot{x} = \frac{1}{t^2 + x^2}, \\ x(0) = a. \end{cases} $
Let $\varphi_a(x)$ denote the solution of the initial-value problem:
$$
\dot{x} = \frac{1}{t^2 + x^2}, \quad x(0) = a. \tag{8.4}
$$

Show that for any $a \neq 0$, the function $\varphi_a$ can be extended to the whole $\mathbb{R}$.

Define
$$
\varphi_0(t) := \lim_{a \to 0^+} \varphi_a(t).
$$
Show that $\varphi_0(t) = \lim_{a \to 0^-} \varphi_a(t)$.

Show that $\varphi_0$ is continuous everywhere and differentiable on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$. Show that it is a solution of the equation on $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$.


I am having a hard time solving part 2. and part 3.
I am not sure what kind of theorems could be used in order to solve it. I assumed I might want to show some sort of uniform convergence but how can I do that if I dont know what my function is?
I will appreciate every hint

$-\varphi_a(-t)$ verify the  same ODE as $\varphi_{-a}$ with the same initial condition so $\varphi_{-a}(t) = -\varphi_a(-t)$

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2354207/show-that-domain-of-maximum-solution-to-ode-x-1-t2x2-is-unbounded-on-the?noredirect=1, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1899035/how-to-this-solve-this-differential-equation?noredirect=1.
